# When did people first think of plastic as bad for environment?

Tags: 20th-century, contemporary-history, natural-resources

I know that at first plastics was thought of as good. It replaced certain natural materials. For some decades after plastics was invented, it wasn’t thought as bad for environment and nature. Since when was it started to think of plastic as bad for environment?

Comment: [Please document preliminary research](https://history.meta.stackexchange.com/a/785/26786). Also, although it might seem trivial, it would be useful to [cite examples](https://history.meta.stackexchange.com/posts/633/edit). It might be more accurate/more illuminating/ to decompose "people think" into groups of people who share opinions.

Comment: To my recollection, plastics did not seem to enter consumer products until almost 1960. It was considered fragile and undependable. Some small molded toys, combs (!), such stuff.

Comment: Roughly around 1970. During the first years of primary school, I don't recall anything about the environment. During the last years it became a regular topic. I confirm @paulgarrett, plastic was seen as something very cheap and unreliable.

Comment: It seems to me that individuals have been ignorant or in denial about various things: insecticides, leaded gasoline, cigarettes while the producers of such products have flat out lied about potential dangers. It takes a long time before enough people care enough that any laws are passed: leaded gasoline was in wide use for 3 quarters of a century.

Comment: Simple google search turned up informative results, although not with a specific date [The age of plastic](https://www.sciencemuseum.org.uk/objects-and-stories/chemistry/age-plastic-parkesine-pollution) and [History of plastics](https://www.sciencehistory.org/the-history-and-future-of-plastics#:~:text=Plastic%20debris%20in%20the%20oceans,increasingly%20aware%20of%20environmental%20problems.) seem instructive and imply that the date is between 1960's and 1970's depending on how you define the terms.